# Narrow Phonetic Transcription: Stretching?

Tags: phonetic-symbols

I use narrow phonetic transcription in my job. The one symbol I need but can't seem to find is a way to mark stretching of the tongue from side to side. Does this exist? I have made up my own, but I'd rather use a standard symbol if possible.

Comment: Is this for transcription of disordered speech, or for some other use? Also, by "stretching the tongue from side to side" do you mean flattening/broadening the lamina, wagging the tip left and right, or something else?

Comment: The way I interpreted it at first glance was "stretching" the sides of the tongue so that the air does not escape, as in [d], unlike in [l], but that of course changes the manner of articulation, thus entirely different symbols would have to be employed.

Comment: I work with non-native speakers of American English. For example, in the word "understand," I have a lot of students from China who slightly broaden the tongue (widening toward the side teeth) when producing the first vowel.

Comment: @Jane Ah, so flattening the lamina?

Comment: I think widening/broadening probably describes it best, but I think we are talking about the same thing.

Comment: @Jane Doesn't broadening the tongue during a vowel result in a change in the quality of the vowel too? In my attempt broadening the tongue while pronouncing /ʌ/ makes it sound more like [æ].

Comment: Great question. The problem is that for my students, it doesn't fully shift it to another vowel; it is just a slightly distorted version of what the vowel should be. This happens with other vowels as well. For example, the /oʊ/ sound may be produced with less gliding of the lips than we expect to hear in American English, or with the tongue in a slightly lower position than we would expect, but not enough that the vowel is heard as a completely different vowel sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no official (or even conventional) symbol to describe that gesture. If I had to pick a symbol to describe "tongue spreading", I might pick `U+20E1`: combining left-right arrow above. Here it is on a schwa: ə⃡

I would choose that because `U+034D` (combining left-right arrow below) is used in the IPA extension for disordered speech to describe lip spreading, so there's a natural parallel there.

Comment: U+20E1 is "COMBINING LEFT RIGHT ARROW ABOVE", not below, i.e. the superior version of U+034D. I wouldn't use it to describe a lingual gesture precisely because the inferior version is used to denote lip spreading in extIPA.

Comment: @Nardog thanks for catching the above/below typo, I've corrected it. Not sure I understand your objection though: lots of diacritics have different semantics when superior vs. inferior; extIPA even seems to do this quasi-systematically (e.g. superior/inferior combining "bridge" indicating involvement of upper/lower teeth, respectively).

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing the symbols in your responses (I'm sure it's a problem on my end), but I was able to look up the codes. Thanks so much for the description and information. U+20E1 is exactly what I'm using! Do you have any sites I can look at with more detailed information on diacritics?

Comment: @Jane I use https://r12a.github.io/pickers/ipa/ a lot. Aside from the click-copy-paste functionality, note the tools in the upper right (esp. "show codepoints") and at the bottom ("add code points" and "search for"). If you're looking for *usage* information, though, it won't help.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you mean by "stretching the tongue from side to side". You can do that with your fingers (if you have a dry tongue), but otherwise it's not possible -- the tongue doesn't stretch that way. There is no symbol to denote this, since the situation you're describing does not exist. Presumably you mean something else -- we'd have to know what you're referring to.

Based on the comments, it appears that the question is about laminal sounds, which are notated with the diacritic ̻ . Although it is usually added to consonants, nothing in principle prevents using it on a vowel. The [Tarama variety of Miyako Ryukyuan](https://www.omicsonline.org/open-access/phonetic-features-of-a-laminal-vowel-in-taramamiyako-ryukyuan-2471-9455-1000134-96169.html) is said to have such vowels, and perhaps some Wu varieties of Chinese have them.

Comment: This should be a comment ...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23266)

Comment: @jknappen, The question asks "Does this exist?"  The answer is "No."  I don't see a problem with this answer.